# Increase Performance of SSIS DFT

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2014, ssis-2012

Im loading 13 cr rows of data from DB2 to SQL server. 
currently I have implemented fast load option and set up batch and commit size. thus improved some performance. Please suggest to improve further.

Current version : ssis 2012 and SQL server : 2014

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(
    [ID] [bigint] NULL,
    [CTYPE] [bigint] NULL,
    [A_ID] [bigint] NULL,
    [AC_TYPE] [bigint] NULL,
    [ASS_TYPE] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
    [t_ID] [bigint] NULL,
    [A_T_ID] [bigint] NULL,
    [FLAG] [int] NULL,
    [REGION] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CHANGEDATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [FLAG2] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```